SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above error when connecting laravel to a PostgresSQL docker container
I'm working on a Laravel project that is running independently. on the other hand, I have a dockerized PostgreSQL service that is running without any problem. (note that laravel is a normal project without a Docker container while PostgreSQL is running as a Docker Container).
now when I serve the laravel project by php artisan serve I get this error :
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above

I have already checked this question and done all the solutions provided but the problem I have is slightly different (because both Laravel and PostgreSQL services are separate from each other and one is normal and the other is Dockerized )
I have installed linux/amd64 version on PostgresSQl now.
these are intallled libpq version in my container :
libpq-dev/bookworm-pgdg 16.2-1.pgdg120+2 amd64
libpq-dev/stable-security 15.6-0+deb12u1 amd64
libpq-dev/stable 15.5-0+deb12u1 amd64

I'm using macOS and the latest version of PostgreSQL and updated libpq recently.
The interesting thing is that if I run my laravel project as a container in the same network that PostgreSQL is running I don't have that problem.
what is the solution?
